# What is the legality of copyrighting an already copyrighted and trademarked logo?

Tags: copyright, trademark

Many sites will have links to Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, etc. located on their site usually using logo "badges".  Most of these sites provide their own official badges, but you can also find countless examples of other artist renditions of said logos readily available on the internet.  Most of which are being sold as copyrighted material.

[image]

Can a graphic designer claim a copyright on their interpretation of an already copyrighted and trademarked logo and sell the usage rights to it for profit?

What if they aren't charging a fee but simply asking for attribution due to the copyright?  Still, seems like you probably aren't allowed to copyright something that is already copyrighted.

Aside from selling the work, it's also very obvious that many reputable companies have had their own versions of these logos created not for resale but just to match the theme of their site.  Is that legal?

Comment: For most sites listed there, it seems you're paying for the physical sticker, not for the icons. Most of these icons are by themselves not eligible for copyright, as they're to simplistic.

Comment: "which are being sold as copyrighted material" - I don't see anything that suggests the people selling these items are claiming copyright over the images. They might be licensed, they might be infringed, but I'm doubtful there are Etsy sellers claiming they actually own the copyright to the Facebook logo.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I just pulled that image as an example but many of the "free" ones ask for attribution and attribution is a thing directly related to a copyright claim as far as I know.  And if the works are not copyrighted that would mean I could just screenshot them and use them without paying/attribution?

Comment: @PMF I only see two of them advertising a sticker, the rest are "SVG icons"

Comment: @jesse_b Copying a copy of a copyrighted work is no different than copying the original. You don't get a free pass to infringe copyright when someone else does it first. The true rights holder could still sue you, but the creator of the copy you screenshotted could not, because they didn't have any rights to begin with.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie right so facebook seemingly has no issue with you using their logo to redirect users from your site to theirs but the people trying to sell their logo have no legal right to do so?  Which circles right back to my original question.

Comment: @jesse_b There are limited uses which Facebook allows, like using the logo to redirect people to your Facebook page. They expressly disallow selling merchandise with the logo, or using the logo for other purposes like implying endorsement by or affiliation with Facebook. These sellers are likely violating copyright law by selling FB-branded merchandise, and they're definitely not claiming the copyright for themselves. The question seems to be related to a lot of downstream things that don't really matter once you know these initial copies are not legitimate in the first place.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie right I guess I'm using partially the wrong terminology by assuming the only way they can sell an image is by claiming a copyright of said imagine but they could also be claiming a license I suppose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, note that in many cases logos are protected as trademarks, rather than under copyright laws. The rules which apply can be quite different.

Next, all the original logos can be protected by copyright, or protected as trademarks, or both (or possibly neither, but this is unlikely in this case).

This means that creating a derived version of the original logo may not be allowed at all, depending on what the changes are, and what the original trademark or copyright holder allows or not.

Usually such logos have licenses which allow pretty widespread use without any payment (it's their goal you use them as much as possible to link to them), but the license will normally restrict the use cases (for instance using it to link to them is fine, using it for your own social network is not).

The licenses will also have rules or at least guidelines on what changes you can do to the logo. This can be more or less restrictive (e.g. some will not allow you to change the colours at all).

Now under copyright laws, if someone has a license (generally published, or specifically granted to them) which allows it, they can create derivate works (e.g. a translation, or an adaptation like making a movie from a book...). Derivate works have "double" copyright: the copyright of the original author, and the copyright of the one who created the derivative works (if there is enough "work"/"creation" to benefit from copyright protection).

So if A writes a book and A gives a license to B to make a movie out of it and B makes the movie, then both A and B have copyright on the movie, and C cannot just take the movie and turn it into a cartoon without authorisation of both A and B (though A could have given the right to B to further authorise other derivative works in their license).

In addition, creating a "set" can sometimes benefit from a protection, either under copyright laws, or under other IP laws (such as database protection laws).

Whether the person creating these sets of logos will benefit from actual protection needs to be checked on a case by case basis: in some situation there is no creative work at all, so they don't benefit from copyright protection. Sometimes even the original logo does not even benefit from said protection (but will usually benefit from trademark protection). In many cases, the derivative work may actually not even be legal, if they modified the original logo in a way that is not allowed by the original copyright holder.

Answer (score 12):

### Copyright is... copyright.

Copyright attaches **the moment a creative work is fixed in a tangible medium** (e.g. a file is saved) for the person that acted as the author. This copyright can be transferred automatically to the employer of the author (work for hire), or sold to someone else later (copyright transfer). There's also a requirement of creativity to be met to have a copyright, many logos do not meet that.

Taking an existing work that is still under copyright and making a derivate work without allowance violates the copyrights in the original work: If I reinterpreted Harry Potter in Klingon, that's a copyright infringement. But if I get a license from Rowling, I am allowed to do that. That license gives me the chance to get copyright in my *changes* and *creative expression*, nothing more. I don't gain copyright in the original, I get copyright in my choice of words where several are available.

Those bundles don't sell you just a derivate work, they sell you a file package containing both copyrightable items (icons other than logos, pre-aligned files that just need text altered for use), uncopyrightable items (fonts), and licensed items (at times matching adapted) logos. The package in total has a copyright in the creative choice of putting the pack together and its pre-setups where they exist. This begs the question: do the package makers have a license? And the anwer will likely be, yes. For example the [Instagram Brand Asset License](https://about.meta.com/brand/resources/instagram/instagram-brand/) is rather allowing on a lot of things regarding the logo when it comes to coloration and backgrounding it, but very much not so regarding altering the logo (rotating, twisting, mirroring) and minimum size.

Comment: Thanks.  So if they do have a "license" does that act like a copyright?  IE if I copy their work is it protected?

Comment: I will not engage further, as that would be possibly giving any legal advice.

Comment: Well you wouldn't be but I feel it's pretty fundamental to my question or at least my understanding of the word copyright.  They may have the license to use the logos and sell products that include the logos but does that license give them the ability to copyright artwork that includes the already copywritten material?

Comment: oh, that's foundationally doable.

Comment: @jesse_b: A license is a legal document. It will (should) say with specificity what is and is not licensed, and what actions the license does and does not permit. If the license is unclear, the only recourse is to ask the licensor to clarify.

Comment: @jesse_b "So if they do have a "license" does that act like a copyright? IE if I copy their work is it protected?": If you copy a licensed derivative work without permission then you have infringed two copyrights instead of just one.  Alternatively, to copy the work legally, you need two licenses: one from the creator of the original work, and one from the creator of the derivative work.  Also copyright is about rights, not writing; the past tense is "copyrighted."

Comment: @phoog yeah I can see that but I also would hope reason would prevail on this case.  If I want a black and white facebook logo to match the aesthetic of my site.  Facebook allows me to modify their logo to use on my site, but someone has already licensed a black and white facebook logo so now I'm in copyright infringement if I make my own?   Seems unlikely.

Comment: @phoog yes I always spell it wrong but it is about rights, the right to copy.

Comment: @jesse_b "seems unlikely": in that example, probably so.  A straightforward conversion of a color image to black and white is probably insufficiently creative to give rise to copyright protection for the derivative work.

Comment: @jesse_b See the first paragraph: Copyright requires creativity. Altering a whole logo's color from one to another color isn't creative, the logo itself might not even be creative.

Comment: @phoog right but in almost all examples that would be a similar story.  "I want it a little lighter", "I want it red", "I want it more rounded", etc.  Most modifications you would do would be very close to artistic modifications that have already been done and are for sale on etsy apparently.

Comment: @jesse_b well wanting it red or whatever color requires choosing a shade, and that's more creative.  The point at which the creativity crosses the threshold in any given instance is for a jury to decide, which can only happen if the owner of the copyright in the derivative work sues.  If you put up a red Facebook logo on your website and someone on Etsy has created a red Facebook logo, are they really going to sue?  More likely Facebook will come after you for messing with their trademark.